# Custom Class Property - Dynamic Reference

Tags: c#

I have a set of custom class properties - each property is named the same as values in a database. What I would like to do is dynamically set the value for each property based on a switch.

The custom properties look something like this:

```
    class MyDEF
{

    #region Variable Declaration Section....

    private string _ABC01;
    private string _ABC02;
    private string _ABC03;
    private string _ABC04;

     #endregion 

    #region Property Declaration Section

    public string ABC01
    {
        get { return _ABC01; }
        set { _ABC01= value; }
    }

    public string ABC02
    {
        get { return _ABC02; }
        set { _ABC02= value; }
    }

    public string ABC03
    {
        get { return _ABC03; }
        set { _ABC03= value; }
    }

    public string ABC04
    {
        get { return _ABC04; }
        set { _ABC04= value; }
    }

   #endregion
 }
```

Then the code loading in the values looks something like:

```
    foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                ED = dr["FieldDesc"].ToString();

     switch (ED)
     {
                            case "ABC01":
                                ratesVO.ABC01 = dr["DefaultValue"].ToString();
                                break;
                            case "ABC02":
                                ratesVO.ABC02 = dr["DefaultValue"].ToString();
                                break;
                            case "ABC03":
                                ratesVO.ABC03 = dr["DefaultValue"].ToString();
                                break;
                            case "ABC04":
                                ratesVO.ABC04 = dr["DefaultValue"].ToString();
                                break;
     }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
    foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
    {
                ED = dr["FieldDesc"].ToString();
                MyCustomProperty.ED = dr["DefaultValue"].ToString();
    }
```

Is this possible? If so please provide an example or reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set value dynamically based on property name:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
{
    ED = dr["FieldDesc"].ToString();
    ratesVO.GetType().GetProperty(ED)
                     .SetValue(ratesVO, dr["DefaultValue"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: heh; I was about to say "PropertyInfo.SetValue needs a third parameter", but it looks like they finally added a `SetValue(obj,value)` overload (in .NET 4.5)!

Comment: Maybe I am not declaring the ratesVO correctly. Because when I type ratesVO.  all I see are the properties. I do not see the GetType method or any other methods at all.

Comment: @Darkman: GetType is from object base, check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx, it must exists when you type

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is basically reflection, where (simplified):

```
string propertyName = (string)dr["FieldDesc"];
object value = dr["DefaultValue"];
// assign
obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(obj, value, null);
```

however, reflection has performance impact; it is OK used sparingly, but as part of a data access loop this can really hurt you; you might consider using library support such as [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember) to improve the performance of this significantly:

```
var wrapped = ObjectWrapper.Create(obj);
...
wrapped[propertyName] = value;
```

I would, however, say that there is little value loading things into a `DataTable` just to push them into an object model. You might as well work directly from the data-reader API.

Comment: Thanks - this code is only used sparingly (maybe once or twice a month).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, perform a select on the data table like this. (This is not a perfect code though, you might need refine it.)

```
DataRow[] result = table.Select("FieldDesc='<Required property>'");
        return result[0]["DefaultValue"]
```